# Is it possible to have a header file for a node?

Tags: ros, headers, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm writing a ROS node in C++. I wanted to know if it's possible to have a .h file (in addition to the .cpp file that includes the node's code) for it.  The .h file includes just a bunch of other #include-s, a typedef command, and the declaration of all the functions used by the node.
This way the .cpp file only has an #include for its .h file.
So, is it possible to do that? And what do I need to add to my CMakeLists.txt to make it compile?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/220287/is-it-possible-to-have-a-header-file-for-a-node?/) by [ROSexperimentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24975/rosexperimentin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-11-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes this is possible. You use roscpp, so you can use all aspects of C++.
In your CMakeLists.txt you have to make sure that your include directory is listed in the `include_directories` section.

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2015-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROSexperimentin](https://answers.ros.org/users/24975/rosexperimentin/) on 2015-11-02**:
and that's it? no need to explicitly add the .h file in the add_executable section (or is that just a wrong way to add .h files anyway?)

**Comment by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) on 2015-11-02**:
No that's it. The compiler will search it's include path for the include files.